# Implementing an iterator vs. looping over a list

Tags: python, optimization, iterator

I want to loop over a number of rows in a database and I have implemented an object in order to access the rows. Now when using this object I am not sure about the best practice. Implementing an iterator looks nice in the higher-level script but is somewhat unnecessary.

So I wondered, **what are the benefits and disadvantages of looping over a list vs. a 'proper' iterator**?

Alternatively, would either option make more sense if I changed the structure of my object?

Here is my code using python 2.7:

```py
class process_scope(object):

    __columns = ['id', 'type', 'start', 'end', 'seconds', \
                        'static', 'table_ref']
    def __init__(self, force = False):
        self.force = force
        self._load_timeframes()
        self._reduce_timeframes()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        try:
            return self.timeframes.pop()
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration

    def _load_timeframes(self):
        self.timeframes = ((1, 'type_1', 000, 999, 999, 0, 'table_1'),
                           (2, 'type_2', 000, 999, 999, 0, 'table_2'),
                           (3, 'type_3', 000, 999, 999, 1, 'table_3'),
                           (4, 'type_2', 000, 999, 999, 0, 'table_4'),
                           (5, 'type_1', 000, 999, 999, 0, 'table_5'))

    def _reduce_timeframes(self):
        relevant_timeframes = []
        for tf in self.timeframes:
            tf = dict(zip(process_scope.__columns, tf))
            if tf['static'] == 0 or self.force:
                relevant_timeframes.append(tf)

        self.timeframes = relevant_timeframes
```

Here is the usage option utilizing the iterator...:

```py
for i in process_scope():
    print i
```

...and the option without implementing the iterator:

```py
iter_ = process_scope().timeframes
for i in iter_:
    print i
```

Comment: If python 2.7 has generators, those are an easy alternative to iterators that offer the same lazy benefits.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble There are generators in Python 2.7, however to my knowlege they are more usefull in line or within functions, not when provided by an object. If I'm wrong, how would I integrate one, and what would be the advantage?

Comment: Mutating `self.timeframes` isn't a good way to implement the iterable here. Just make `__iter__` return `iter(self.timeframes)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Does this mean, i don't even need the `next()` method?

Comment: Yes; you only need to implement `next` if *the instance itself* is the iterator (hence it's required when you `return self` from `__iter__`). `next` is implemented by the object `iter` returns.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thats great advice, Thank you!